# Is there a tool like pry in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

With Ruby, you can use Tool [pry](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) to explicitly list breakpoints in your code.

```
binding.pry
some_method          # Execution will stop here.
puts 'Goodbye World' # Run 'next' in the console to move here.
```

Is there a tool like [pry](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) in Kotlin without IDE?

Comment: Is [JDB](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdb/jdb_breakpoints.htm) what you're looking for?

Comment: @NeelKamath yes, how to use it in Kotlin.

Comment: The same way you use it in Java.

First, run the program with the JVM arguments: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005` (or `gradle --debug-jvm` if you're using [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:debugging_java_tests)).

Then, attach the debugger: `jdb -attach 5005`.